# Mac App Store: download but don't install

Tags: mac-appstore

A friend of mine has a crappy broadband connection, and he needs to install the latest XCode 4.1 which is only available on the Mac App Store.

For my part, I have a good connection, but already have XCode 4.2 DP installed on my system.

Is there a way I can download XCode 4.1 from the App Store without installing it (I don't want my 4.2 overwritten), and then hand it to my friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xcode you download from the app store is just an installer, it's not the actual Xcode; downloading it will not compromise your current installation of Xcode (that is if you do not open it).

P.S. The Xcode from the AppStore (4.1) runs only on Lion. For Xcode on Snow Leopard download it from the developer's website(Xcode 3.6).

Comment: Yep, it's only for Lion, we're aware of it. Thanks for noting that it's only an installer, I was thinking it would be so because it needs to install system components, and it's a little more than a "classical" app. Will test and accept your answer if it works.